# Django tables2 external link generation w/ custom parameters

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I have a music related model with Artist and song Title fields and I'd like to add a column that provides a link to search Amazon's digital music store using the artist and title from the given row on a table using Tables2. Here is what I have but not sure how to add the Amazon column and provide the Artist and Title fields to the Amazon URL?

models.py:

```
class Artist (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track (models.Model):    
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Artist")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Title")
```

tables.py:

```
class amazonColumn(tables.Column):

    def render(self, value):
        return mark_safe('https://www.amazon.com/gp/search?ie=UTF8&index=digital-music&keywords={{artist}}-{{title}}', value) # not sure how to pass artist and title records


class TrackTable(tables.Table):

    amazon = amazonColumn()

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
        fields = ('artist', 'title', 'amazon')
```

Comment: [Here's a great tutorial](https://pyformat.info/) on string formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`format_html`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html).

Furthermore, you'll need to add `record` as a parameter to the render function, which allows you access its other attributes:

```
class AmazonColumn(tables.Column):
    amazon_url = '<a href="https://www.amazon.com/gp/search?ie=UTF8&index=digital-music&keywords={artist}-{title}">Amazon</a>'

    def render(self, record):
        return format_html(self.amazon_url, artist=record.artist.name, title=record.title)
```

You might have to set `empty_values=()` where you instantiate the `AmazonColumn` in your table.

Comment: Thanks, I think you have a typo return render_html should be format_html.  I also changed the amazon_url to amazon_url = '<a href="https://www.amazon.com/gp/search?ie=UTF8&index=digital-music&keywords={artist}-{title}"">Amazon</a>' for the actual link